# SQL Server: Using partition-by with reversed team names

Tags: sql-server, partition-by

The below code averages (for any given the game) the scores for the last 5 times the teams met i.e for the row in orange, all the games highlighted in green are averaged.

The problem I have is I want a similar calculation for the reverse (the game is AvC but I need the average for CvA games i.e. highlighted in blue).
I've tried to reverse the team1 and team2, concat the teams in reverse order but it still ends up sorting and providing the same result.

I assume I need some way to reverse the team1 and team 2 in the current row only (e.g. if the date is greater than getnow()) which would then allow the averages to work.
I'm hoping someone can tell me I'm over-complicating things and if there is some simple workaround I'm missing.  Any help appreciated as always.

```
SELECT
AVG(score) OVER (Partition by (team1+team2) ORDER BY date ASC ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS Average_H2H_Score
FROM Scores
```

[image]

Comment: Think I may have solved it by creating head to head averages in a separate table and then doing two separate joins (with team1 and team2 reversed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up resolving the problem by calculating the averages and then inserting into a separate table along with a row number to identify each H2H.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY team1+team2 ORDER BY date DESC) AS RN
```

Then did a  LEFT JOIN back to the original table with the following criteria (team1=team2, team2=team1, and row number =1).  Using a row number resolved the problem of the date not aligning when joining the tables.